# Artificially increasing query time

Tags: oracle, performance, query-performance

Very weird question:

Is there any way to artificially inflate the amount of time a query will take? An infinite loop would be great.

```
SELECT CLAIM.UNIT_PRICE FROM CLAIM WHERE CLAIM.DATE_PROCESSED>SYSDATE-10;
```

Needs to take enough time for our DBA to analyze something while it's running.

Comment: `dbms_lock.sleep` ?

Comment: This is a query, not a procedure. I need the query itself to be running for a  few minutes, not pause for a bit before it runs instantly.

Comment: What is this "something" the DBA must analyze that he can't do by tracing the sql statement? It's all there, on the trace files, v$ views... Once we know this "something", we can further help.

Comment: Can't you just write a query that takes longer time to execute ?  cartesian join with the same table (especially multiple times) (e.g `FROM CLAIM a, CLAIM b, CLAIM c` ) will significantly increase time. You can also run other queries in parallel session that takes lot's of cpu time, so your query will get less. Also, you can modify the query and make it hierarchical which normally slows the query down.

Comment: Find a faster DBA instead.

Comment: please can you explain what you want to achieve and why?

Comment: I don't understand why? If he's wanting to do some tracing etc, just set tracing at the session level. If he wants to do some tuning work, you can do it post-execution. Is he wanting to click the active session in a TOAD window or something? Ask him why.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with a select * from a large table and where 1=0. Gather stats, save them using dbms_stats and then apply those stats to the large table. You will essentially tell Oracle that the large table has no data, which would favor full table scans. You can also try switching the optimizer mode to first_rows_1 or invalidating some indexes.